# Sorting a list in python with items that begin with specified letters

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

If I have a list:

```
list = ('john', 'adam', 'tom', 'danny')
```

and I want a sorted output with the items where the first letter is between `'a'` and `'h'`, like:

```
('adam', 'danny', 'john')
```

which sorting function in Python do I need to complete this task?

This is the code i tried:

```
l = list()

while True:

    s = raw_input("Enter a username: ")

    l.append(s)

    print sorted(l)
```

Comment: 1. That's not a list, that's a tuple. 2. Don't name your own variables (even if they are lists) `list`. 3. This isn't a code-writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: this is my code which i tried: l = list()

while True:

s = raw_input("Enter a username: ")

l.append(s)

print sorted(l)  the problem is that i want to print those names that start with letters a through h

Comment: Well you're making no attempt to check the first letter of the name, before or after it goes in the list, and you're sorting on every step of the loop (which will never end). I suggest you take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 distinct things: a list with just the elements that begin with an acceptable letter, and then the sorted version of that list.  The former can be done with a list comprehension (although, as @jonrsharpe points out, you look like you want tuples, so you meat need to convert to a list & the convert the result back).